# Changing root view navigation controller

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am changing the root view of a navigation controller in code  like this :

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:    
[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
NewViewController *nvc = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:nvc];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Do i need to release the current view controller manually after replacing it with the newviewcontroller or is this done automatically ?